# Can we do Alias for SQL entries?

Tags: sql

I got accents in my database and while querying, I want my database to be accent insensitive. Unfortunately, I cannot use `collate` because my company does not want to change their DB structure. Can we provide alias for database entries? I looked up alias but I didn't get what I was hoping for.

Comment: Please include some sample data and expected output in the post

Comment: What **concrete** RDBMS are you using? Please add a relevant tag -  `oracle` ? `postgresql` ? `db2` ? `mysql` ? `sql-server` ??

Comment: your question interests us but lacks information please add some